# How to equally distribute files to users based on file sizes?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, resources, distribute

I have N files with various file sizes and also M users.

What I want to do is to use an algorithm in C#, C++ or pseudocode that will equally distribute the files to the users.

If file sizes were not in the game it would be something like N/M files per user. So, I could randomly select N/M files for each user (maybe some users could not take part if M > N and no more files were left). But, now I have the file sizes in the game and I want to auto assign the files to users with file sizes in mind.

A file can be related only with one user. So, when a file is related with a user it cannot be used again.

A user can be related with many files.

If files are less than the users (N > M) some users may or many not take part at all.

Also, these cases are possible N < M, M > N and M = N and the algorithm should equally distribute files to users.

If anyone can help me I would appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the code you have tried and whats not working with it?

Comment: I have no code at the moment. I don't even know what algorithm or math to perform for doing such a task.

Comment: By my experience the community isn't going to want to just figure this out for you. You need to show some effort. What you think could work etc... This seems like a homework problem

Comment: I really don't want to give me the solution but a way of how I could implement it. Maybe there is a well-known algorithm for such situations. Later on I will implement the algorithm in my application. For example I would like something related to path finding in games and you could have purposed me the A* algorithm and a link for reference. That is what I want. Not the solution. I can implement it having a guideline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is homework, it's a stinker!

It's the optimization version of the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and it's NP-hard (i.e., you're not going to be able to solve it efficiently) even when you have only two users.

There is a greedy algorithm which gives a decent approximation to the optimal arrangement, and does it in `O(n log n)` time. That is what I would go with if I were you, unless you have a very clear need for perfect optimality. This is the pseudocode, taken from the Wikipedia page I linked to above. It is for two sets (i.e., `M=2`), but easily generalises. The basic idea is that at each stage, you assign the current file to the user who has the smallest total.

```
INPUT:  A list of integers S
OUTPUT: An attempt at a partition of S into two sets of equal sum
1 function find_partition(S):
2     A ← {}
3     B ← {}
4     sort S in descending order
5     for i in S:
6         if sum(A) <= sum(B)
7             add element i to set A
8         else
9             add element i to set B
10    return {A, B}
```

Perfect optimality is certainly achievable in principle, but there are two issues to think about.

1. If nothing else, you could try every possible assignment of files to users. That would be very inefficient, but it's known to be an NP-hard problem, which means that whatever you do, you're going to end up with something with an exponential running time.
2. It's not absolutely clear what *optimal* means in a case with more than two users. (It's clear for two, which is why the partition problem is expressed in terms of two.) For instance, suppose you have eight users. Which is the better allocation: `[8,4,4,4,4,4,4,0]` or `[5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3]`? You need some well-defined metric that determines the "badness" of an allocation before you can try to minimise it.

Comment: Great man! Thank you very much. So, it is the partition problem. I could generalize it for N users (instead of two A, B) by finding the user with the minimum sum and add the file size of the next file to him/her. Right? But, as you said this is a greedy algorithm and not always produce perfect results but an approximation. Is it possible to produce a perfect optimality somehow? If there is no way I might use this algorithm since it is also fast o(n log n).

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis You're welcome :) I've added something about producing an optimal solution.

Comment: I really didn't understood your new notes (especially the second). Could you please explain it to me? Related to [8,4,4,4,4,4,4,0] or [5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3]...

Comment: If you've got two users, and you allocate them total sizes of A1 and A2, then *optimal* means as close as possible to A1=A2; and *as close as possible* means you're minimising the difference between A1 and A2. But suppose you've got three users, and you allocate them total sizes of A1, A2 and A3. What exactly are you trying to minimise? There isn't a clear concept of the "difference between" three numbers. Since they're all non-negative, you might go with minimising the sum of their squares, or something, but it's not obvious what *optimal* means here.

Comment: How really I could do this? Another question is if the greedy algorithm works without problems with file sizes which are not close each other. Say values like 12, 100, 200000, 10000, etc.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis The greedy algorithm is by far your best bet on all counts. You should be aware that with very unbalanced file sizes you'll end up with very unbalanced results whatever you do: with the example you mention, and four users, the perfectly optimal solution is still very unbalanced. There's nothing you can do in a case like this.